# CSS calc() subtract negative value

Tags: html, css, css-calc

Is it OK to subtract a minus number, like this?

```
width: calc(35% - -20px);
```

Because if I do as above, it behaves differently than if I do this:

```
width: calc(35% + 20px);
```

Here you can see the difference:
http://nightly.gamempire.it/

- Put the window of the browser < 1200px and > 1000px
- Analyze the #gallery_thumb element

Actually you see that it has: calc(35% - -20px)
If you change to calc(35% + 20px), it breaks (the #gallery_thumb will be less higher than the #gallery_img).

Why is this? Can you not subtract a negative number?

Comment: Aren't the 2 statements the same? -- == +

Comment: It seems not: I added more informations to the question to help in debugging.

Comment: @OscarFanelli if I try this on http://jsfiddle.net/aksyx/1/ both look the same

Comment: With `calc(35% + 20px)` (with space after + sign) it seems to work exactly as with `calc(35% - -20px)` (Firefox 22, Chrome 28). Are you sure that you've not tested `calc(35% +20px)` (without space), which seems to be invalid?

Comment: fantastic, my editor add a space that it wasn't recognized as a space (in "35% + 20px", so it was recognized as "35% +20px").. thanks! :)

Answer (score -4):

`calc()` is a native CSS way to do simple math right in `CSS` as a replacement for any length value (or pretty much any number value). It has four simple math operators: `add (+)`, subtract `(-)`, multiply `(*)`, and divide `(/)`.

**[More info](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)**

**[Link Two](http://davidwalsh.name/css-calc)**

**[Link Three](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)**

**[calc() function browsers compatibility](http://caniuse.com/calc)**

Comment: I added more informations to the question to help in debugging.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.